# How to write hexadecimal values of members of struct to unsigned char array in C++?

Tags: c++

I have uint32_t type members in a typedef struct which are initialised with 4 byte hexademical values. I want to write each byte of the member variables to an unsigned char array.

This is the struct:

```
#pragma pack (push, 1) 
struct pcap_hdr_s {
    uint32_t magic_number;
    uint16_t version_major;
    uint16_t version_minor;
    int32_t thiszone;
    uint32_t sigfigs;
    uint32_t snaplen;
    uint32_t network;
};
#pragma pack (pop,1) 

pcap_hdr_s pcap_hdr_tr;
pcap_hdr_tr.magic_number = 0xa1b2c3d4;
pcap_hdr_tr.version_major = 3;
pcap_hdr_tr.version_minor = 1;
pcap_hdr_tr.thiszone = 0;
pcap_hdr_tr.sigfigs = 0;
pcap_hdr_tr.snaplen = 65535;
pcap_hdr_tr.network = 0;
```

I want the char array to look like:
unsigned char a[] = {0xd4 0xc3 0xb2 0xa1 0x3 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xff 0xff 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0};

Comment: Look up `memcpy`.

Comment: Why `struct obj` when your source is `uint32_t`?

Comment: Clarify what you want and what you've tried, please. This could mean a few different things.

Comment: @stark The source is not a `uint32_t`. The source is a class with `uint32_t` members.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have some confusion between a number and  the representation of that number.

11, XI, 0xB, 013 are different textual representations of the same number: ELEVEN.

You apparently want to convert the bytes of a 4-byte integer into four bytes. One issue you have right away is how the system represents numbers.

If you have a 4-byte integer initialized to 0x12345678 the system could store that as

0x12
0x34
0x56
0x78

or as

0x78
0x56
0x34
0x12

A lot of what I am going to say now depends upon your system and your compiler.

The are severa ways to do what you want to do.

- union
- reference
- pointer
- copy from one to another

e.g.:

union 
{
  struct_obj structure ;
  unsigned char a[sizeof(struct_obj)] 
} ;

struct_object structure ;
unsigned char *a = reinterpret_cast (&structure) ;

I cannot recommend doing this kind of thing because of the unpredictable behavior but this appears to be what you are asking for.

Comment: The union is fine (and unnecessary because you can already alias with `unsigned char*`). However it's not guaranteed to do what you want, because of padding. Though it'll probably work. OP would be better off avoiding the original problem entirely (whatever that is)

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear. I've added the part of code for which I was seeking some help.